# Send data from kafka to s3 using python

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-kafka

For my current project, I am working with Kafka (python) and wanted to know if there is any method by which I can send the streaming Kafka data to the AWS S3 bucket(without using Confluent). I am getting my source data from Reddit API.

I even wanted to know whether Kafka+s3 is a good combination for storing the data which will be processed using pyspark or I should skip the s3 step and directly read data from Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka S3 **Sink** Connector doesn't require "using Confluent". It's completely free, open source and works with any *Apache Kafka* cluster.

Otherwise, sure, Spark or plain Kafka Python consumer can write events to S3, but you've not clearly explained what happens when data is in S3, so maybe start with processing the data directly from Kafka